# REST or Alternative Method for New User && New Site && Assign User to New Site as Admin?

Tags: multisite, api

Looking for a method to add a new user to a site, assign them to that site as an admin.

API does not seem to support this. Any functions I should be looking at as alternatives?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user is probably where you want to start :)

Comment: Doh. 3 hrs of googling and plugins and chat rooms, and its simply the create user function + https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpmu_create_blog/

Answer (score 0):

The api does support it, but not with the obvious `wp_create_user`. You need [wp_insert_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user).